# Fetching facebook likes count with jquery goes wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

i have a little script which fetches the likes and tweets count about a url via jquery. Now it works great, but when a certain page has 0 like/shares, then jquery returns 'undefined' because the 'shares' part is not shown in the output.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    url = "http://awebsitehere.com/";
    beforecounter = " <b>";
    aftercounter = "</b>";

    // Get Number of Facebook Shares
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/'+url+'&callback=?',
        function(data) {
            $('#facebook').append(beforecounter + data.shares + aftercounter);
    });

    // Get Number of Tweet Count
    $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='+url+'&callback=?',
        function(data) {
            $('#twitter').append(beforecounter + data.count + aftercounter);
    });


})
```

How would I have to edit this script to display 0 instead of undefined when facebook has got 0 shares/likes for a certain url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#facebook').append(beforecounter + (data.shares || 0) + aftercounter);
```

and likewise for the twitter value.

Comment: @Boon glad it helped. Consider selecting the right answer for your question

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to create a username of your page(see under your page name @username. Just click it...)

Then goto https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and get an access token key

Then script something like that

```
function facebookLikesCount(access_token, pageusername)
{
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+pageusername+"?fields=likes&access_token="+access_token+"";

$.getJSON(url,function(json){
alert(json.likes);
});
}

facebookLikesCount('your accesstoken', 'pageusername');
```

its work for me.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question